# copying/dragging address in all cells in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have property data across a number of years. However, I only have the address of the property in data from 2007 onwards. I want to copy/drag the address of the property (as per the property number) into all entries pre-dating 2007.

Sample data is below

```
structure(list(year = c(1990L, 1992L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 1990L, 1992L, 1998L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L), property = c("1182 047", 
"1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", 
"1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", 
"1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", "1182 047", 
"1182 047", "5421 047", "5421 047", "5421 047", "5421 047", "5421 047", 
"5421 047", "5421 047", "5421 047", "5421 047", "5421 047"), 
    street = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "400 MINER RD", "400 MINER RD", "400 MINER RD", "400 MINER RD", 
    "400 MINER RD", "400 MINER RD", "400 MINER RD", "400 MINER RD", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), city = c("", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "ORINDA CA", "ORINDA CA", 
    "ORINDA CA", "ORINDA CA", "ORINDA CA", "ORINDA CA", "ORINDA CA", 
    "ORINDA CA", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), city_overflow = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    zip = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "94563", 
    "94563", "94563", "94563", "94563", "94563", "94563", "94563", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), name = c("BARSAMIAN BETSY A", 
    "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", 
    "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", 
    "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", 
    "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", 
    "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", 
    "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", 
    "BARSAMIAN BETSY A", "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", 
    "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", 
    "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", 
    "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", 
    "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING", "ZHANG ZHI HAO & JIANG JIE YING"
    ), period = c("0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0106", 
    "0106", "0106", "0106", "0106", "0106", "0709", "0709", "0709", 
    "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1500", "0000", "0000", 
    "0000", "0000", "0000", "0106", "0106", "0106", "0106", "0106"
    ), type = c("individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", 
    "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", 
    "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", 
    "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", 
    "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", 
    "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", "individual", 
    "individual")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want every row to contain the address associated with its property number which can be found in all data entries post 2007.

Comment: Maybe you would like to show us your code, what you have tried so far, so we understand where we can help you.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, wasn't sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::fill()`
would be an elegant solution for this kind of issue. We need to make sure first,
that the data is sorted by the `property` and `year` columns, `dplyr::arrange()`
works for that. In order to ensure that the address data is never pasted into
the cells of another property, we use `dplyr::group_by()`.

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

prop_df %>% 
  arrange(property, -year) %>% 
  group_by(property) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(street, city, zip), ~ifelse(. == "", NA, .)) %>% 
  fill(street, city, zip) 
#> # A tibble: 30 x 9
#>     year property street    city    city_overflow zip   name      period type   
#>    <int> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>         <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  
#>  1  2015 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 1500   indivi…
#>  2  2014 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 1014   indivi…
#>  3  2013 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 1014   indivi…
#>  4  2012 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 1014   indivi…
#>  5  2011 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 1014   indivi…
#>  6  2010 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 1014   indivi…
#>  7  2009 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 0709   indivi…
#>  8  2008 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 0709   indivi…
#>  9  2007 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 0709   indivi…
#> 10  2006 1182 047 400 MINE… ORINDA… ""            94563 BARSAMIA… 0106   indivi…
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

Another approach could be to first build an address dictionary for each
propery using `dplyr`’s `select()`, `filter()` and `distinct()` and
then join that back into the original dataset with `full_join()`.

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

address_dict <- 
  prop_df %>% 
  select(property, street, city, zip) %>% 
  filter_at(vars(street, city, zip), ~. != "") %>% 
  distinct()

prop_df %>% 
  select(-c(street, city, zip)) %>% 
  full_join(address_dict)
#> Joining, by = "property"
#> # A tibble: 30 x 9
#>     year property city_overflow name       period type     street   city   zip  
#>    <int> <chr>    <chr>         <chr>      <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>
#>  1  1990 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0000   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#>  2  1992 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0000   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#>  3  1998 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0000   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#>  4  1999 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0000   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#>  5  2000 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0000   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#>  6  2001 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0106   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#>  7  2002 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0106   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#>  8  2003 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0106   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#>  9  2004 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0106   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#> 10  2005 1182 047 ""            BARSAMIAN… 0106   individ… 400 MIN… ORIND… 94563
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: This `, .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002bd19dd1ef0>` needs to be removed!

Comment: Thank you for your response! There seems to be an error in all the addresses matched after the sample I provided...not sure why it's messing up the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` and `zoo::na.locf`

```
library(data.table)
#Columns to replace values
cols <- c('street', 'city', 'city_overflow', 'zip')

#Replace empty values with NA
df[, (cols) := replace(.SD, .SD == '', NA), .SDcols = cols]
#Replace NA's values with next values. 
df[,(cols) := lapply(.SD, zoo::na.locf, fromLast = TRUE),.SDcols = cols, property]
```

Comment: Thanks- this code works for the first two properties after which is says "Supplied 20 items to be assigned to group 3 of size 40 in column 'street'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code." Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user12801590 Maybe look at the groups which fail. They have some different properties than the rest of the group.

Comment: None of the properties, except the first two, are successful.